# Getting rails 3.1 working with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, content-type

I know this is a stupid questions and have very similar ones out there but none of them really solve my problem:

```
#application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .

#form
<%= form_for @comments, :remote => true, do |comment| %>
.....
<% end %>

#controller
def create
  @comments = Comment.new params[:posts]
  if @posts.save
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html {render 'something'}
      format.js {render :content_type => 'text/javascript', :layout => false}
    end    
  end

#app/view/comment/create.js.erb
alert("hello world, please work!");
```

With the code, I just want to add the comments without refreshing the page, and the posts are appended to the page.  Anyhow, whenever I submit a post, it always goes to the "respond_to" format.html line, which i have no idea why.  When I look at the generated form, it reads fine with data-remote sets correctly:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="...." data-remote="true" id="..." method="post"
```

When I look at the HTTP accept it is

```
HTTP_ACCEPT: "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" even I set the content_type to be text/javascript.
```

I found one say that by adding charset :content_type => 'text/javascript;charset=UTF-8' would help, but it does no magic.

I also try adding this onto the application.js but also no magic

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
  }
  });
});
```

Can anyone guide me on this? And btw, the errors in my Webbrick server shows "406 unacceptable error something".  I am really frustrated on this.  What I suspect is something about the content type that I am doing it wrongly...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting data-type attribute to the form.

Reference: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/#example

Comment: Also have a look at the dataType parameter of following page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ .

Comment: It does not works...

I just edit 
    <%= form_for @comments, :html=>{:'data-type' => 'script, :remote => true, do |comment| %>

but it still goes directly to respond_to html line, I even try to remove the format.html line, with only format.js left, but it still not doing any good

Comment: typo :'data-type' => 'script'

Comment: I actually try this, but does not work too.., am I doing something wrong?


`jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/post/create"
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script",
    success: function(data) {
       alert("hello");
    }
}`

Comment: Firstly, don't we need a comma before cache in the above code. Check out the rails server log and check whether you are getting the request in html or in js/script type.

Comment: i just check on the rails development.log and it says

Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML

I guess it's still html

Comment: I did all kind of tweaks regarding content-type, but still no hope...and will update if I got the solution...